# How to pass data more than 1024 byte in Work Manager?

Tags: android-workmanager

I have used Work Manager to upload images to fire base.
I am converting Interaction Report Class to JsonString and sending it to work manager as a parameter so that I can deseriailize it back to Original object and use the url from the image details, otherwise I would have to send each url. 
But in some cases it throws an exception:

> can not send data more than size 1024 bytes

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This is the documented limit of WorkManager's Data class.  See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Data, where it lists:

"This is a lightweight container, and should not be considered your data store. As such, there is an enforced MAX_DATA_BYTES limit on the serialized (byte array) size of the payloads. This class will throw IllegalStateExceptions if you try to serialize or deserialize past this limit."

Answer (score 0):

You can't but maybe this solution can help you in some cases by compress and decompress the data.

Try to compress and put it to Data.Builder()

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun compress(str: String?): String? {
    if (str == null || str.length == 0) {
        return str
    }
    println("String length : " + str.length)
    val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val gzip = GZIPOutputStream(out)
    gzip.write(str.toByteArray())
    gzip.close()
    val outStr = Base64.encodeToString(out.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT)
    println("Output String lenght : " + outStr.length)
    println("Output : $outStr")
    return outStr
}
```

and decompress it in Worker class

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun decompress(str: String?): String? {
    if (str == null || str.length == 0) {
        return str
    }
    println("Input String length : " + str.length)
    val gis = GZIPInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(str, Base64.DEFAULT)))
    val outStr = ""
    val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val buffer = ByteArray(256)
    var n: Int
    while (gis.read(buffer).also { n = it } >= 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, n)
    }
    println("Output String lenght : " + outStr.length)
    return String(out.toByteArray())
}
```